# Omitting a Number in a txt file

Tags: c#, winforms

How to omit a number in a txt file?

I have been trying to omit a number from a text file when using `File.ReadAllLines` i had notes on it and i can not find them and the example is like this

`1 In the land far away.`

Isn't there a simple code to omit numbers. I had the notes but I forgot where i put them.

so any help will be greatly appreciated.

I had started deleting each number with the replace feature. However I was trying to remember the code snippet for it.

```
_recognizer.LoadGrammarAsync(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(File.ReadAllLines(@"Dictionary.txt" )))));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RegEx to replace all number by an empty string :

```
string value = "1 In the land far away.";
value = Regex.Replace(value, @"^[\d-]*\s*", "");
// value = " In the land far away."
```

Or in your case, since ReadAllLines return a string array, you could do something similar :

```
string[] fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(@"Dictionary.txt");
for(int index = 0; index < fileContent.Length; index++)
    fileContent[index] = Regex.Replace(fileContent[index], @"^[\d-]*\s*", "");

_recognizer.LoadGrammarAsync(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(fileContent))));
```

Comment: i edited the question and added my code, unfortunately it did not work when i added the code in the button event.

Comment: I've edited my answer to incorporate your code.  If it still doesnt work, you will have to tell me more about what is not working.

Comment: it works and now i have to go to phase two of my speech engine. I am doing a list of phrases in a txt, and then going to try to do a db and see which is fastest. The current list is 35,000 lines.. so atleast now i don't have to delete each number 35,000 times

Comment: So if want to add to it say for example i want to remove the `Gen |1|1| ` how would i incorporate that

Comment: Gen |1|1|?  From what?

Comment: i have the complete Bible in a txt document, the beginning of each line starts with `Gen |1|1| ` so in order to delete that i would need to use `@"^[\d]" + [\d]" + [\d]*\s" + [\d]" + [\d]" + [\d]" + [\d]" + [\d]*\s"` if i remember correctly

Comment: A database would be a better idea than a large text file.  You could use a simple SQLite database.

Comment: It starts exactly with "Gen |1|1| or it could be something else?  So basically, your text file is really a CSV file with 4 columns?

Comment: `Gen|1|1| In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.~` this is the bible format and Gen changes respectively

Comment: Well ok, i'm not too familiar with the bible format.  But it is really a CSV file and it would be much easier to treat is as so instead of doing multiple replaces or an horribly complicated one.  I feel like this is becoming a totally different question though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122869/discussion-between-kinetic-and-campnerd).